# Zeichenhäufigkeit des Deutschen

Tags: big-list

Was ist die **Zeichen**häufigkeit des Deutschen. Ich meine nicht die **Buchstaben**häufigkeit, die finde ich überall.

Mit "Zeichen" meine ich jedes Zeichen(/jeden Unicode-Codepunkt) das in einer einen deutschen Text enthaltenden Datei vorkommen kann (zb. abcäöü123.!?,-+;:_<>%()€µ¶æ).

Comment: Was genau meinst Du mit Zeichenhäufigkeit? Interpunkiton?

Comment: Ich vermute, dass, zumindest in Anbtracht deutscher Schachtelsätze, es sehr wahrscheinlich ist, dass das Komma mit Abstand das Häufigste ist ^^

Comment: @miep Das würde ich auch vermuten. Aber der OP lässt uns leider im Dunkeln, was genau er meint.

Comment: Ich glaube, das i-Tüpfelchen ist das häufigste Zeichen (einschließlich derer, die auf äs, ös und üs herumlungern).

Comment: "Zeichenhäufigkeit" sollte eigentlich ein wohlbekannter Begriff sein. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstabenh%C3%A4ufigkeit

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Auf einem ä, ü öder ö habe ich noch nie ein I-Tüpfelchen gesehen. Auch auf einem I noch keinen verwaisten Ö-Punkt. :)

Comment: Deutschen Text enthaltende Dateien können auch SVG-, HTML-, PDF-, ODT- und 100 andere Dateiformate sein. Deren Formatartefakte willst Du vielleicht nicht wissen, wie die <Tag/>-Zeichen aller XML-artigen Dateien, oder? Sollen die Zeichen danach berechnet werden, wie oft sie geschrieben werden (1x pro Dokument) oder auch danach, wie oft sie gelesen werden, also Zeitungsartikel viel häufiger als Firmentexte (Bestellungen, Rechnungen)? Je nach Gattung + Kontext gibt es sicher erhebliche Unterschiede - welchen Sinn hat es, über alle Gattungen hinweg eine Statistik zu bilden und wer sollte das tun?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Siehe: http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/fileadmin/kl/derewo/DeReChar-v-uni-204-a-c-2018-02-28-1.0.html

Dieser Liste des Instituts für Deutsche Sprache entnehme ich, daß das Leerzeichen am häufigsten auftritt. Die seltenste Ziffer ist die Sieben, die häufigste die Null. Das seltenste nicht unter *other characters* subsumierte Zeichen ist ƒ (U+0192, `LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK`) mit einer relativen Auftretenshäufigkeit von 0,0000001075 %.

```
RF              AF          U       D   GC  G   N
0.000000001075  193         U+0192  402 Ll  ƒ   LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK
0.000000002038  366         U+0131  305 Ll  ı   LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I
0.000000003012  541         U+017D  381 Lu  Ž   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON
[...]
0.000057891007  10398241    U+0026  38  Po  &   AMPERSAND
0.000065771506  11813717                        OTHER CHARACTERS
0.000066762957  11991799    U+00C4  196 Lu  Ä   LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
[...]
0.077477574885  13916332506 U+006E  110 Ll  n   LATIN SMALL LETTER N
0.127847330583  22963624830 U+0065  101 Ll  e   LATIN SMALL LETTER E
0.140692439455  25270831869 U+0020  32  Zs      SPACE

Total characters counted: 179617554197
```

Comment: Interessant, dass "7" seltener ist als "8" und "9". Ich vermute, dass unter den für diese Statistik ausgewerteten Texten eine ganze Menge mit Preisangaben (Schwellenpreise wie 4,99 €) gewesen sind.

Comment: Das fand ich auch interessant. Siehe dazu auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benfordsches_Gesetz

Answer (score 2):

Antwort wohl: das Spatium.

Begründung: Wenn du Absatz-Endmarken mitzählst (wie deine Sammlung ja nahelegt), also dem Leser des Endprodukts üblicherweise nicht sichtbare Zeichen, die der optischen Strukturierung dienen, dann müsstest du auch Spatien (Leerzeichen) zählen, und vermutlich sind dann genau diese die häufigsten Zeichen.

Comment: Es war allerdings nicht einfach nach dem häufigsten Zeichen gefragt worden.

Answer (score 0):

Eigentlich wäre das eine einfache Programmierübung: schreibe ein Programm dass schlicht und einfach alle Zeichen zählt und lass es über Texte drüber laufen. 1.000.000 Zeichen sollten kaum ein Zeitaufwand sein und wären definitiv eine gute Probemenge für relativ genaue Ergebnisse.

Falls du bis Sonntag Zeit hast, da würde ich vllt dazu kommen...

Comment: Das Problem dabei ist, dass man dafür einen für die deutsche Sprache repräsentativen Text braucht. Wenn ich so einen hätte, hätte ich so ein Programm schon längst geschrieben.

Comment: Das ist doch wohl kaum eine Antwort auf die Frage? -1

Comment: Die Methode geht in die richtige Richtung, der Rest ist (ohne dir zu Nahe treten zu wollen) etwas ... naja ^^. 1.000.000 Zeichen entsprechen ca. 555 Standardschreibmaschinenzeichen (30 Zeichen á 60 Zeilen). Das sind ca. 2 etwas dickere Bücher bei heutigen Schrifttypen. Das ist bei weitem kein repräsentativer Querschnitt. Vor allem, wenn man bedenkt, aus wie vielen Bereichen man Textproben benötigt, um diese ganzen Zeichen abzudecken. Allein diese auszuwählen und maschinenlesbar zu besorgen ist ... interessant :D . Die Methode der akzeptierten Antwort verwendete übrigens 238 Milliarden Zeichen.

Comment: gibt es nicht bei google für wissenschaftliche zwecke eine texte sammlung in allen möglichen sprachen? da kann man ja dann drauf zurück greifen?! die ist nur EXTREM groß weshalb man dann am besten auch noch auf denen ihren cloud computing service zurück greift... aber repräsentativen text in geeigneter menge auftreiben ist ehrlich gesagt nicht das problem... ansonsten müssen eben die Bestsellerbücher der letzten paar jahre und die Zeitungstexte verschiedenster Zeitungen dafür herhalten.